# how to create PostgreSQL 'text' column using SQLModel for FastAPI

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, sqlmodel

I'm using SQLModel for FastAPI.
But I don't know how to create 'text' column type using it.

How can I create 'text' column?
Thank you for reading it.

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field


class BaseModel(SQLModel):
    col_1: str = Field(default='Y')
    col_2: str = Field(default='N')
    col_3: str = Field(default='0')
    col_4: str = Field(default='0')
```

---

this is my solution!

```py
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field
from sqlalchemy import Column, TEXT


class BaseModel(SQLModel):
    col_5: str = Field(sa_column=Column(TEXT))
```

Comment: You dont need to force it to be TEXT, by default it will make the column VARCHAR which is an alias for TEXT on Postgres. Refer to SQLModel website here: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/create-db-and-table/#text-or-varchar

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TEXT

from sqlmodel import SQLModel, Field
from sqlalchemy import Column


class BaseModel(SQLModel):
    col_5: str = Field(sa_column=Column(TEXT))
```

Comment: Don't forget to add sqlalchemy into your requirements.txt